# Agregar atributo a un XML

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Estoy tratando de consumir un servicio SOAP, estoy tratando de generar el XML pero no logro agregarle el atributo

Esta es mi clase de identidad llamada Pago, donde esta la estructura del XML a enviar
esta clase la genere manualmente

```
 public partial class Pago
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Pago")]
    public class Pago
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumeroPago")]
        public int NumeroPago { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NombreUsuario")]
        public string NombreUsuario { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body"  , Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public class Body
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Pago")]
        public PagoPago { get; set; }
    }

    
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope"), ]
    public class Envelope
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap")]
        public string Soap { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Ejecuto este método  para generar el xml

```
 public string GenerateXMLPago(int NroPago, string NombreUsuario)
    {

        Envelope xml = new Envelope
        {

            Body = new Body
            {
                Pago= new Pago
                {
                    Xmlns = "http://tempuri.org",
                    NombreUsuario = NombreUsuario , 
                    NumeroPago = NroPago,
                    
                }
            }
        };

        string xml2 = "";           


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = getNamespaces();
        using (StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, xml , ns);
            xml2 = writer.ToString(); 
        }
     
      

        return xml2;
    }

    #region XML Entidades
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces getNamespaces()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");            
        ns.Add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope");
        
        return ns;
    }
    #endregion

    public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
    }
```

El método me devuelve el siguiente xml, pero según la documentación del SOAP deberia de agregarle el SOAP:

```
<Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Body>
    <Pago xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <NumeroPago>1234</NumeroPago>
      <NombreUsuario>xxxxx</NombreUsuario>
    </Pago>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

como por ejemplo este XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Pago xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <NumeroPago>1111</NumeroPago>
      <NombreUsuario>xxxx</NombreUsuario>
    </Pago>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

La diferencia es el atributo SOAP, manualmente le agregue el atributo SOAP y el servicio si llego a procesarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Clase Envelope y Body

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{

    private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public EnvelopeBody Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{

    private Pago pagoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public Pago Pago
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pagoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pagoField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Y la clase pago

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Pago
    {

        private ushort numeroPagoField;

        private string nombreUsuarioField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort NumeroPago
        {
            get
            {
                return this.numeroPagoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.numeroPagoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string NombreUsuario
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nombreUsuarioField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nombreUsuarioField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Para crear tu Xml

```
var Pago = new Pago() { NombreUsuario = "Juan El Pagador", NumeroPago = 1 };
            Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
            envelope.Body = new EnvelopeBody() { Pago = Pago };



            string xml = "";
            using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                ns.Add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope");

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(envelope.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, envelope, ns);
                xml = stringwriter.ToString();
            }
```

Lo que hace la magia es esto en la clase Envelope

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope", IsNullable = false)]
```

Y esto en la de pagos

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope")]
```

---

Hola para lo que me preguntas, primero copias tu XML (ctrl + c) y luego vas a visual studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias , me ayudo mucho , pero como llegas a generar la clase , utilizas algún programa?

Comment: Hola @Samuel, te respondí arriba